# Ant Design table search and sorter customization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is there a simple fix to prevent the table from sorting when clicking into input on table header?

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q-57471984-searchintable-forked-qqh14p?file=/src/App.react.js)

I tried to add onclick handler to the input search field, but did not help.

```
onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of events bubbling. You can read about events propagation here https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing.

In your case you should `stopPropagation` on input click event.

```
<Input
     ...
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }}
   ...
 />
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for providing solution + docs!